# ScrollLeft is not working on React useRef in useEffect when using framer-motion drag

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I am having a problem with setting the scrollLeft property of a React ref (scrollContainerRef) inside a useEffect hook in my React component. I want the horizontal scroll position of an element to be reset to 0 whenever the active state changes.

However, this problem only occurs when I add drag='x' to the motion.div from Framer Motion. If I remove drag='x', the scrollLeft property works as expected.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
const scrollContainerRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(()=>{
    if(active==='all'){
        setFiltered(ended)
        scrollContainerRef.current.scrollLeft = 0;
    }
    else if(active==='atp' || active==='wta'){
        setFiltered(ended.filter(match => match.tournament.category.flag === active && match.status.type === 'finished'))
        scrollContainerRef.current.scrollLeft = 0;
    }
    // ...more code
},[active])
```

The ref is assigned to a DOM element like so:

```
<motion.div
    ref={scrollContainerRef}
    className='flex w-full gap-2 md:gap-6 '
    drag='x'
    dragConstraints={{right:0, left:-leftConstraint}}
    >
    // ...more code
</motion.div>
```

But, the scrollLeft assignment doesn't seem to be working when the drag='x' prop is included. The horizontal scroll position of the referenced element does not change when the active state changes.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!